# How to properly run CMD as a child process?

Tags: windows, inheritance, winapi, console

I have a problem with running child processes in CMD run by `CreateProcess` with custom input/output handles. Things go like this:

In my own `cmd_text.exe` I run `cmd.exe` using mentioned `CreateProcess` function with changed handles, which are formerly created pipes with `CreatePipe`, then I run 2 threads which manage input and output, here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

wchar_t cmdLineMutable[] = L"cmd.exe";
wchar_t directory[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32";

DWORD inputThread(LPVOID parameter) // parameter is input write pipe end
{
    HANDLE hInputRead, hInputWrite;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    hInputRead = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hInputWrite = (HANDLE)parameter;

    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(20);
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 1024);
        ReadFile(hInputRead, buffer, 1024, &bytesRead, NULL);
        WriteFile(hInputWrite, buffer, bytesRead, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

DWORD outputThread(LPVOID parameter) // parameter is output read pipe end
{
    HANDLE hOutputRead, hOutputWrite;
    char buffer[8192];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    hOutputRead = (HANDLE)parameter;
    hOutputWrite = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(20);
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 8192);
        ReadFile(hOutputRead, buffer, 8192, &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
           WriteFile(hOutputWrite, buffer, bytesRead, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void main()
{
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    HANDLE hInputRead, hInputWrite, hOutputRead, hOutputWrite,
        hInputThread, hOutputThread;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));

    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);

    CreatePipe(&hInputRead, &hInputWrite, &sa, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hOutputRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    CreatePipe(&hOutputRead, &hOutputWrite, &sa, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hInputWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = hInputRead;
    si.hStdOutput = hOutputWrite;
    si.hStdError = hOutputWrite;

    CreateProcessW(
        NULL,
        cmdLineMutable,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        0,
        NULL,
        directory,
        &si,
        &pi
    );

    CloseHandle(hInputRead);
    CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);

    hInputThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, inputThread, hInputWrite, 0, NULL);
    hOutputThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, outputThread, hOutputRead, 0, NULL);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    TerminateThread(hInputThread, 0);
    TerminateThread(hOutputThread, 0);
    CloseHandle(hInputWrite);
    CloseHandle(hOutputRead);
}
```

This method works as the CMD "welcome" message pops up in the `cmd_test.exe` and i can type several basic commands, including `dir` or `ping`. The problem starts when I try to run another program also written by myself (from this CMD), even the simple `printf("im alive");` kind of program. I cannot input or output to this program, even using `WriteConsole` with `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` as the `hConsoleOutput` parameter. It's kind of confusing for me, I guess there is some inheritance issue here but I'm not sure since the "im alive" program doesn't crash after running, so does the previously run CMD.

I also tried to run the CMD with the help of pseudoconsole functions (`CreatePseudoConsole`, `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` etc.) and then everything works just fine, i get proper output (and input) from my "im alive" program, but then I get an issue with diacritical signs, which for some reason aren't properly written onto the screen and that annoys me a bit. How can I fix that so e.g. I can set my locale or code page in some way and fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code has no error checking!

Comment: Have you read MSDN'S article on [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)? You are missing steps in your setup.

Comment: @Anders this is just a sample, I didn't include it here to make it clear, no errors in original one though

Comment: @RemyLebeau what steps am i missing? the only difference is that in article they use some readonly file to buffer data between pipes, i use a normal stack buffer

Comment: @pazdinho_ you are not handling the pipe inheritance correctly, and you are not closing the unused pipe ends while the threads are running so the child process can exit correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i fixed it, added `SetHandleInformation` calls to appropriate pipe handles after `CreatePipe` calls and closed unused pipe handles after creating child process. still, no effect - the "grandchild" doesn't inherit input/output

Comment: @pazdinho_ please update your question with the actual code that does and does not work. Do you have the problem if `cmd_text.exe` runs the `"im alive"` program directly? Why are you running commands like `dir` and `ping` using `cmd.exe` at all, instead of using native APIs like `Find(First|Next)File()` and `IcmpSendEcho()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i updated it now, should be ok. yes, i have the problem when i run `"im alive"` directly by calling `CreateProcess` - if i don't change anything related to handles in `STARTUPINFO` structure, it's working completely fine (output is visible) but it breaks when i try to set my own input/output handles - output is invisible UNLESS i explicitly use `WriteFile` call with `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` as the handle - normally i use `printf` to output text

Comment: @RemyLebeau i discovered that calling `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` finally outputs the text, why would i need to call it in this specific situation?

Comment: @pazdinho_ depending on standard library implementation, stdout I/O is usually buffered, typically line-buffered. The buffer is not flushed until either a line break is written, or the buffer fills up, or the buffer is flushed manually (as you discovered), or the process exits. Try printing a line break in your text, eg: `printf("im alive\n");`

Comment: @RemyLebeau to be honest, thats actually what i do. i forgot to mention it because i thought it was irrelevant, but the `"im alive"` line is ended with `"\n"` so its `"im alive\n"`

Comment: @RemyLebeau though it is not printed in the "grandchild" process unless i explicitly use `fflush`